# laravel socket to sync entire table

Tags: laravel, сокет

Есть таблица, на 1000 строк, я сейчас получаю по 10 первых, и затем через через settimeout спрашиваю сново бд и получаю данные опять. и так каждый раз...

Можно ли как то реализовать, что подключение было активным постоянно, и любое изменение в бд немедленно отображалось.

Если можно любые подобные примеры, тк то что я увидел сейчас - это нужно настраивать queue, event listener + broadcasting который по сути шлет только уведомления, о том что произошло обновление. Мне не понятно на данный момент вообще с чего начать. Подскажите направление хотя бы

Comment: Как пример - используйте либо Laravel Websockets, либо в связке с Pusher. При изменении в таблице высылаете сообщение о том, что изменилось. Для того чтобы синхронизировать данные в самом начале вам понадобится метод для получения текущего «снимка» таблицы, а в websockets будете передавать дельту (изменения)

Comment: @DanielProtopopov а если изменение сделали прямо в бд... ест ьвозможность отловить такое? laravel echo + socket io уже настроил

Comment: А зачем пытаться скрещивать ужа с ежом? Какой смысл? База данных создана для хранения данных и их структурирования, упорядочивания.